# Django Logger vs Logging Middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-logging

I want to log every request sent to Django.

There are some posts online about logging middleware. 
The Django documentation talks about logger configuration and it seems that I can set it up to log everything without writing middleware.

- Can I log everything without middleware?
- What can middleware give me that a well-tuned Django logging config cannot?
- Can I log `INFO` level messages, with `DEBUG = False` and no middleware?
- How much extra load does logging everything add to my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if want to log every request, in that case, you should use **Logging** in middleware
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/428/

Comment: This was what I ended up doing... way back then. Thanks for confirming ;-)